# Grub Customizer does not start

Tags: grub2

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 as a second OS dual-booting with Windows. And by default I need to boot to Windows.

So, I decided to install Grub Customizer through the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa: danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

But when I try to run Grub Customizer, a form appears for a password. After entering the password, nothing happens.

What to do?